# Laravel popover containing dynamic data with AJAX on link hover

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, popover

In my Laravel app, I have a list fetched from database similar to the following image:

[image]

Each title has ID no. associated with it [i.e. "The Nanny" has ID no 7662 ] and each title has specific tasks similar to the bellow picture. For example, the entry "The Nanny" has the following tasks: 
[image]

What I want to do is to hover over on the title link and display a popover box and on hover the popover will fetch the tasks for that specific ID/entry using ajax. The popover box will be dismissed with a close button. I tried to load the view of the task list in ajax, but it didn't work. Can anyone please tell me how can I go about this? Any link to any resources that might help. I have seen resources for PHP-MySQL but nothing specific that deals with Laravel.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you show your code, please?

Answer (score 1):

For popover u can use [bootstrap popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/) if u using bootstrap. So for ajax on hover over popup u can use 'mouseenter' event, i.e.

```
$("item").mouseenter(function() {
  $.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': 'handlers/route_request.php',
    'dataType': 'html',
    'success': function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
  })
});
```

You should learn about some JS methods to append content to specific DOM element.
The best way i think is to use some JS-framework, i.e. i'm using Vue especially it's allready within Laravel project by default.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am working on a legacy laravel app (5.2) which doesn't come with vue :(